# How can I show Azure Application Insights in a Dashboard

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights, webapi, appinsights

I have published by web services in the Azure App Service and integrated Application Insights to it. The Azure App Insights is giving me the insights about my web services.
Now, I want to create a dashboard similar to the Azure App Insights dashboard in a web app or in the Power BI.
I want to connect to the Azure App Insights, get data and show it in the dashboard.

Can anyone help me how can I do this or let me know any suggestions in following different approaches.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-powerbi

Answer (score 0):

You can get the App Insights query in the desired format and then feed it to the PowerBI. The behavior would be similar to calling an API and binding the response to the dashboard.